# Can I pass an algorithm as a parameter in java?

Tags: java, sorting, methods, merge, quicksort

I'm performing some measuring tests on sorting algorithms.

I create this method that calculates the time that seletion sort needs to order an array

```
public static double timeToSelectionSort(Double[] arrayOfNumbers) {

      double timeToSelectionSort =0;
  Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

  Selection.sort(arrayOfNumbers);

  timeToSelectionSort = stopwatch.elapsedTime(); 

  return   timeToSelectionSort;
  }
```

The problem is that I need to create this method for all of my sort algorithms(insertion, selection, quicksort, mergesort...)

Is there any way of passing these algorithms as a parameter of this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking about the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), as EJoshuaS noted. The purpose of the strategy pattern is to solve exactly the problem you're describing - you'd like to apply *some* operation, but you don't necessarily know *which* operation at compile-time, hence you define a "strategy" interface that allows you to separate the code that's *invoking* the strategy from the code that is *defining* the strategy.

In your case, you want to sort an array, but want to decouple that from which algorithm will actually do the sorting operation. So, first you define an interface to describe sorting:

```
/** Interface responsible for sorting an array of doubles. */
@FunctionalInterface // we'll come back to this
public interface Sorter {
  /** Sorts the input array in ascending order. */
  void sort(double[] arr);
}
```

Now that we have an interface, we can write code that uses that interface, despite not knowing what the implementation (e.g. bubble sort, quick sort, etc.) will be yet:

```
/** Given an array and a sorting strategy to apply, prints the sorted array. */
public static void printSorted(double[] arr, Sorter sorter) {
  sorter.sort(arr);
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Great, we're done! Mostly... Now we need to create some implementations of `Sorter` in order to invoke `printSorted()`. While I'll leave the implementations themselves up to you, the boilerplate would look like:

```
/** Sorter strategy applying the bubble-sort algorithm. */
public class BubbleSorter implements Sorter {
  @Override
  public void sort(double[] arr) {
    // TODO
  }
}
```

Once you have one or more `Sorter` implementations you can invoke `printSorted()`:

```
printSorted(new double[] {5.0, 3.0, 10.0}, new BubbleSorter());
```

The task (printing a sorted array) is now decoupled from both the array to be sorted *and* the sorting strategy to be used, and you can easily substitute different strategies.

---

But wait, what about Java 8?

Lambdas, and functional programming in general, are essentially a nice syntax for applying the strategy pattern (forgive the gross oversimplification), and it turns out they work quite nicely for this sort of task.

I annotated `Sorter` as a [`@FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) above, which notes that the interface is intended to be used to construct lambda expressions. Any operation that takes a `double[]` and doesn't return anything can be passed as a lambda into our `printSorted()` function. For example, we can use [`Arrays.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-double:A-) as our strategy:

```
printSorted(..., d -> Arrays.sort(d));
```

Even better would be to use a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) (`Arrays::sort`) here, but I used a lambda for clarity.

You may notice that `Sorter` looks a lot like a `Consumer<double[]>`. In practice, it *is* a `Consumer`, so we could just remove that interface and have `printSorted()` take a `Consumer<double[]>`. Which you should prefer (reusing `Consumer` or defining your own interface) is largely a matter of preference, but in [different contexts both are reasonable choices](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/347612/88040).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, absolutely. This is what's known as the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). Basically, create an interface, have each algorithm be a class that implements the interface, and have the parameter be of the type of the parameter (and I'm using C# conventions here)

```
public interface SortingAlgo {
  void sort(...);
}

public class QuickSort implements SortingAlgo {
  public void sort(...) {
    ...
  }
}

public void methodYouWantToAcceptAlgo(SortingAlgo algo) {
  ...
}
```

Etc.

Comment: I'd suggest a lambda function, which is a simpler concept than the strategy pattern... though it is surely good to note it exists.

Comment: @paulotorrens That's a valid thing to do, too

Comment: I think that Strategy Pattern is a little confuse to me :/ How can i do it with a lambda function?

Comment: This was my first thought for a solution when I read this question as well, but based on how I read the question, I think the OP is looking for some way to do it without having to create a bunch of extra functions (whether those are independent functions like `timeToSelectionSort(...)`, `timeToQuickSort(...)`, etcetera or functions wrapped in separate classes defined to implement a common interface).

Comment: @paulotorrens lambdas *are* the strategy pattern. You can use a lambda expression as an argument to the `MethodYouWantToAcceptAlgo` method.

Comment: @Dantex what about the strategy pattern are you confused by?

Comment: @paulotorrens In this case, using a lambda expression is just another way to supply an implementation of the interface, and is hence still logically the Strategy Pattern. The fact that the timing method accepts the algorithm (aka the Strategy) as a parameter, is the main part of the *pattern*.

Comment: @dimo414 how to apply it to this case :/

Comment: Is there any way to use [Consumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) ?

Comment: @Dantex Yes, you can use `Consumer`. Didn't you see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43566238/5221149)?

Answer (score 1):

1. If your sort algorithms are all implemented in different classes, create an interface with the method to be called, and have all the classes implement that interface.
   E.g. this is how `List` is an interface with multiple implementations that have different performance characteristics.

   ```
   public interface Sort {
       void sort(Double[]);
   }
   public class Selection implements Sort {
       // code here
   }
   public static double timeToSort(Double[] input, Sort sort) {
       Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
       sort.sort(input);
       return stopwatch.elapsedTime();
   }
   public static void test(Double[] input) {
       System.out.println(timeToSort(input, new Selection()));
   }
   ```
2. If your sort algorithms are all static methods, use the [`Consumer<Double[]>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) interface, and supply the implementation using Java 8 method references.

   ```
   public class Sorts {
       public static void selection(Double[] input) {
           // code here
       }
   }
   public static double timeToSort(Double[] input, Consumer<Double[]> sort) {
       Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
       sort.accept(input);
       return stopwatch.elapsedTime();
   }
   public static void test(Double[] input) {
       System.out.println(timeToSort(input, Sorts::selection));
   }
   ```
3. If your sort methods don't all share same signature, use lambda expressions. This is a variant of #2.

   ```
   public static void test(Double[] input) {
       System.out.println(timeToSort(input, (a) -> Sorts.selection(a)));
   }
   ```

Comment: For #3 you still don't need to use a lambda, a method reference will do.

Comment: @dimo414 I know, I just wanted to show OP how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Strategy Pattern will be very useful in this scenario.

[Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern):

- Defines a family of algorithms, encapsulates each one, and makes them
  interchangeable. Strategy lets the algorithm vary independently from
  clients that use it
- The algorithms can be used interchangeably to alter application
  behavior without changing its architecture.
- By encapsulating the algorithm separately, new algorithms complying
  with the same interface can be easily introduced.

Other simple way is to use [Lambda Function](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html)

Comment: and how can i apply lambda function in this case?

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/strategy-pattern-using-lambda this link will help you understand it. (Just try to use your algorithms classes instead of provided classes - see 3rd example in the article)